# Herstein - Topics in Algebra - Polynomial rings page 157

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In Chapter 3.9 of his book "Topics in Algebra" , 2nd ed, Herstein describes an example of a Quotient ring, namely $ F[x]/(x^3-2) = F[x]/A $ where $F = Q $ the rationals, and $(x^3-2) = A $ is the principal ideal generated by $(x^3-2)$. At some point, the simplification is made from $(a_1x  +   A)$ (the quotient ring represented by $a_1x$)  to $ a_1(x + A)$. How is this simplification achieved? I get $(a_1x+A)=(a_1+A)(x+A)$ and then no further. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is part of the definition: you define the operation $\cdot$ by : $$\begin{array}{rcl} \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q[X]/A & \longrightarrow & \mathbb Q[X]/A \\ (\lambda,x+A) & \longmapsto & \lambda\cdot (x+A):=(\lambda x+A) \end{array}$$
where $x+A$ is the equivalence class represented by $x$.

Since the map is defined with respect to representative of an equivalence class, you need to prove that this operation does not depend on any choices of representative to check that this map is well defined:

If $y$ is an other representative of the quotient class $x+A$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb Q$, then $x=y+a$ with $a\in A$.
Hence, $$\lambda \cdot (x+A) = \lambda x+A = \lambda(y+a)+ A = \lambda y + \lambda a +A = \lambda y +A =\lambda\cdot( y+A)$$ since $\lambda a\in A$.

So this operation of $\mathbb Q$ on $\mathbb Q[X]/A$ is well defined, it does not depend of any choices. Furthermore, it is compatible with the addition in $\mathbb Q[X]/A$ so you can play with it as usual.

Comment: It should be already known to everyone studying abstract algebra that quotient vector spaces exist ...

Comment: Sure, but this is maybe what ghtorpe is trying to do.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that it is not really necessary to talk about polynomials here. The issue is a much more basic one, answered in every text on linear algebra.

Comment: So if $ \mathbb{Q}[x] /A $ is then a vector space with the scalar multiplication explained in Bebop's answer, how do the concepts of basis (and linear independence and span) translate into this  $ \mathbb{Q}[x] /A $ creature? Any basis would be infinite then? Also, as  $ \mathbb{Q}[x] /A $ is a Quotient Ring endowed with a multiplication, does this multiplication have a special name in its role as a vector space? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually in your case, since $X^3-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, the quotient ring is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-algebra and also a field. You can check that its dimension is $3$ (same as the degree of $X^3-2$) and a basis is given by $(1,\alpha,\alpha^2)$ where $\alpha$ is the equivalence class of $X$. Moreover, the only rule you have in this field is $\alpha^3=2$.